# Storing hierarchical network data in MySQL for use by PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project that stores IPv4 networks in a database, the network is stored as an unsigned integer in one column and the bitmask length (cidr) in another column. Each network is "owned" by a user (unsigned integer pointing to a "users" table). The subnets are also arranged in a hierarchical manner, e.g.

```
1.0.0.0/16 - owned by user 'A'
 1.0.1.0/24 - owned by user 'B'
 1.0.2.0/24 - owned by user 'C'
  1.0.2.0/26 - owned by user 'D'
 1.0.3.0/24 - owned by user 'E'
```

etc

Now the tricky bit comes because each user should be able to view/edit all subnets under them, so user 'A' above can access all the subnets shown, user C can access 1.0.2.0/24 and 1.0.2.0/26 and so on. The number of levels in the tree is variable and only restricted by the maximum length of the bitmask, so in theory you could have:

```
1.0.0.0/8
 1.0.0.0/9
  1.0.0.0/10
   1.0.0.0/11
.....
```

All the way up to 1.0.0.0/32 with each successive "owner" being able to access all the subnets under them.

Any suggestions as to the best way of storing this in MySQL? and the best way to ascertain if a particular user should have access to a particular network, using PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What if you store the 'owner' ip addresses as bit masks ( 4 columns? ) and store the CIDR in a separate column. Then to figure out who 'owns' a particular address you would build a mask from the ip portion out to the length of the CIDR and do a 'select  ( checked_ip & stored_ip )'.